# hunspell suggestions are comming up with the wrong encoding

Tags: c++, encoding, wxwidgets, punctuation, hunspell

I started working on a text app using wxRichTextCtrl (wxWidgets) and hunspell. My problem is the suggestions are coming messed up when there is a punctuation.

I used the hunspell function to return the dictionary encoding and it was reporting ISO 8859-1. I went to the .dic and .aff files and saved as UTF-8 (I was setted with UTF-8 WITH BOM before). That didn't helped.

I have tried using the std::string as well, but it didn't help (I was using wxString).

Can you help me with this problem?
Thank you!

***Edit***

So, a minimal reproducible example would be very big, as it is a wxWidgets project. I'll try to give as much code as possible:

```
// (...)
cRichText* m_richTextCtrl;
m_richTextCtrl = new cRichText(this, ID_RICHTEXT_CTRL, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxVSCROLL | wxHSCROLL);

Hunspell m_Spell{ "dicts/pt_BR/pt_BR.aff", "dicts/pt_BR/pt_BR.dic" };

// (...)
mapentry list = m_Spell.suggest("elevadr");
for (auto& word : list)
{
    m_richTextCtrl->AppendText(wxString::Format("%s ", word));
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ Hi, I added some. Don't know if its enough.